POOL HOUSE AND NEC 225.30
When I built my home in 2012, I provided 16 extra circuits/breakers in a 400 AMP main panel and routed all 10 AWG, 14 AWG wires for 15 and 20 AMP loads underground to where the Pool house would be.
Using MIL-STD 2000 and 454 terminated wires to terminal blocks/crimped lugs - 1 block for Hot (black), 1 block for Ground (Green), and one Block for Common (white). This is an outdoor box designed for outdoor wiring.
Inside the building I have a location for pulling wires from the metal enclosure under ground to the CMU block in a closet that is just a steel electrical junction box enclosure that is 24" by 20" by 10". This is where all the wires converge so they can be earlier pulled to the load.
There are 16 GFCI plugs, 2 fans 17 feet height, 1 mini-split and 9 coach lights.
Since the main breakers are already at the Main 400 Amp panel we saw no need for any sub-panel in the pool house.
The pool house is about 50 feet from the main building.  If I understand NEC 2017 225.30 - its talking about feeders - which I think is the 3 cables that route to a sub panel - I have no such sub panel since I already have the 400 Amp panel - I don't think this applies in my case - what law forces me to put in a SUB panel when I have already have 1.25" Conduit with ground and hot, and a separate 3/4" with only common (white). This is Arizona, maricopa county
Clarification: The main house has one feeder - that is from the telephone pool to the 400 Amp Main panel
225.30 says "Where a branch circuit or feeder originates in these additional buildings or other structure, only one feeder or branch circuit shall be permitted...."
The branch circuit does not originate at the pool room - it originates at the main panel. The power comes from the pole, not from the pool room.
I see no difference from this and converting my play room into a big bedroom where I add more outlets, lights.

Feel free to [edit] some formatting into this if you'd like people to be able to read it. A wall o'text is hard to digest.

I take it you are in an unincorporated portion of Maricopa County from the way you're talking?

You can't separate all your neutrals (which you called commons and the NEC calls the grounded conductor) into a separate conduit. See 300.3)(B) Conductors of the Same Circuit. All conductors of the same circuit and, where used, the grounded conductor and all equipment grounding conductors and bonding conductors shall be contained within the same raceway

If you're in Maricopa City, 15.05.100 seems to state that you must comply with 2017 NEC. If you're not in Maricopa City (or any other city), it appears that Arizona State does not directly require compliance with the NEC (maybe), but your insurance might withdraw coverage if you do not.

In this question, you are not using the word "service", "feeder" and "circuit" in the correct ways.  This may be part of your confusion.

One feeder per outbuilding
Whoever specified running sixteen circuits to an outbuilding was not qualified to design electrical work.  To start with, they wasted a staggering amount of money.
Nope, you're only allowed one feeder to an outbuilding.  You don't do 2-2-2-4 feeder at a dollar a foot plus a $70 subpanel just because it's cheaper, you do it because it's required.
Under NEC 2020, you're allowed up to six circuits to an outbuilding if they all have disconnects where they enter the building and right next to each other.  Further if the outbuilding constitutes a dwelling (hey, there are "pool houses" with bedrooms and ranges), the disconnects need to be outdoors. But sixteen is still way too many.  And you were not under NEC 2020 in 2012.
Also a 24x20x10" box is larger than a 20-space subpanel, so I really don't see the advantage in doing that.

Since the main breakers are already at the MAIN 400 AMP panel we saw no need for any sub-panel in the pool house.

Yeah, fire that person, their reasons are dead wrong. Consider all their work suspect.

If I understand NEC 2017 225.30 - its talking about feeders

No, it's very plainly talking about "branch circuits or feeders".  It's in plain language and repeated 5 times LOL.  Read it yourself on page 14 here.

what LAW forces me to put in a SUB panel when I have already have 1.25"

LAW is absolutely correct.  Pull the 16 cables (33 wires?) out of the conduit and install quantity one feeder, #2 aluminum if you need 90A for the pool house Load Calculation, #1 if you want 100A, #1/0 if you need 125A.
Note that your subpanel can't be in a clothes closet and the working space must be kept clear at all times, so face it toward a threshold, path or hallway where that will happen naturally.
In Arizona there's nothing really wrong with the panel being outside (it'll be harder on the G/AFCI breakers though) and there must be an outside disconenct if it qualifies as a dwelling per local definitions.  (e.g. has a stove).

Got it so there is no ARS law that says this is the way you must do it - it is your opinion and the industry. - Also if this BS continues I will just join the pool room to my main house and now it is part of the house - since it is only 10 feet away then we are just wring a new room. The MAIN shut off on the main panel is the disconnect.

also added this note from the "supposed" standard 225.30 says "Where a branch circuit or feeder originates in these additional buildings or other structure, only one feeder or branch circuit shall be permitted...." The branch circuit does not originate at the pool room - it originates at the main panel. The power comes from the pole, not from the pool room.

Without the main source of power, the telephone pole, main 400 amp panel there is NO CIRCUIT - the circuit only exists because of the supplied power, without it there is no circuit. This is why the main panel is where the circuit originates.  All I would have is a bunch of plugs and switches that do nothing without the power supply.

DEFINITION OF BRANCH CIRCUIT A branch circuit is that part of an electric circuit that extends beyond the last circuit breaker or fuse. It goes from the breaker box to the electrical devices in your home. Simply put, branch circuits are the last part of the main electrical circuit, and supply current to various electrical devices.

You clipped your 225.30 quote off before the critical part of that paragraph. "...to supply power back to the original building". First paragraph says one set of wires to the additional structure, then second paragraph you quoted from says only one set back.

@Shan "Got it so there is no ARS law that says this is the way you must do it - it is your opinion and the industry." No, you seem to be hell-bent to misread facts and code and the very validity of code itself to suit your pre-decided destination.  I doubt any further discussion will be useful . That said, I presumed that your pool house was an outbuilding.  NEC rules say if it is connected by a breezeway, it is not an outbuilding.

Like Elon Musk, I will always challenge the why, why are we doing this what is the reason - being a former BSEE I know there is no safety reason for this - That is what GFCI, Breakers that trip do that is their job. Without people like me challenging the status quo  - and just be cause some person put in a IBC x number of years ago without REASONS why we do it with out justification, There are Borg automatons who will just do whatever is said - then this country will truly be Communism and not  republic is short order.  We need laws that require any code be backed up with proof and the reason.

And that reason better be sound, logical, make sense, and not obsolete.

@Shan if you want to argue Code you're on the wrong website. Submit Code change proposals to NFPA (but you have a gross misunderstandng of the process).  Requests for waivers to your AHJ, all else to your insurer. My abandonment of this argument is not an endorsement of your plan.

https://homeinspectioninsider.com/subpanel/  Is a Subpanel Necessary?
Are you considering adding a new electrical sub panel because your main panel has no more breaker spaces? Wait, you may not need a new subpanel.
If your main breaker box allows for tandem breakers, you can increase your house panel capacity by replacing the existing 1-pole breakers with tandem breakers. Tandem breakers allow for two branch circuits to share one breaker space.
The new circuit breakers can handle the additional branch circuits without needing an electrical panel upgrade or a new subpanel.
